# Infinite Runner Unity2d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, when I start the game, my character can jump on the first platform (because that is the manually placed platform), but I cannot jump on the spawned floors. BTW I am able to run on the floors and I know my jump works correctly.

I have tried so many ways of collider detection I am going crazy and I know its a simple fix that I just can't figure out.

I expected my character to be able to jump on the duplicated platforms but the character just doesn't do anything at all.
If anyone is willing to take a look that would be very helpful. - Nick

P.S I know my code is messy.

CODE:

```
#Code that is on my player script#
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TouchControlsKit;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

public class Attack : MonoBehaviour
{


    const float k_GroundedRadius = .2f; // Radius of the overlap circle to determine if grounded

    [SerializeField] private LayerMask m_WhatIsGround;

    [SerializeField] private Transform m_GroundCheck;

    private bool m_Grounded;

    public Collider2D objectCollider;

    public Collider2D anotherCollider;

    [Range(0, .3f)] [SerializeField] private float m_MovementSmoothing = .05f;

    private Timer t;

    private Timer a;

    private float timeStamp;

    private float die = 0;

    public GameObject bullet;

    private bool m_FacingRight = true;

    public float move;

    private Vector3 velocity = Vector3.zero;

    public GameObject idle_0;

    public playscript play;

    public Transform player;

    private Rigidbody2D m_Rigidbody2D;

    [SerializeField] private float m_JumpForce = 200f;

    bool swing = false;

    bool isgrounded = false;

    public bool canJump = false;

    bool slide = false;

    public Transform groundLayer; // Insert the layer here.

    public Vector2 jumpHeight;

    private Vector2 touchOrigin = -Vector2.one;

    public Vector2 moveSpeed;

    public bool run;

    Collider2D m_Collider;

    // variable to hold a reference to our SpriteRenderer component
    private SpriteRenderer mySpriteRenderer;

    // This function is called just one time by Unity the moment the component loads
    private void Awake()
    {
        // get a reference to the SpriteRenderer component on this gameObject
        mySpriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        animator.SetBool("death", false);
    }



    public Animator animator;

    Animator anim;
    int swingHash = Animator.StringToHash("swing");


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {



        timeStamp = Time.time + 5;

        m_Collider = GetComponent<Collider2D>();

        run = false;

        m_Rigidbody2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();

        animator.SetBool("isgrounded", false);

        isgrounded = false;

        canJump = false;

        animator.SetBool("swing", false);
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        m_Grounded = false;

        // The player is grounded if a circlecast to the groundcheck position hits anything designated as ground
        // This can be done using layers instead but Sample Assets will not overwrite your project settings.
        Collider2D[] colliders = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(m_GroundCheck.position, k_GroundedRadius, m_WhatIsGround);
        for (int i = 0; i < colliders.Length; i++)
        {

            if (colliders[i].gameObject != gameObject)

                animator.SetBool("isgrounded", true);

                m_Grounded = true;
        }
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        anotherCollider = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Ground").GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();

        objectCollider = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<CapsuleCollider2D>();

        Vector3 targetVelocity = new Vector2(move * 2f, m_Rigidbody2D.velocity.y);
        m_Rigidbody2D.velocity = Vector3.SmoothDamp(m_Rigidbody2D.velocity, targetVelocity, ref velocity, m_MovementSmoothing);
        animator.SetBool("run", true);



        if (move > 0 && !m_FacingRight)
        {
            // ... flip the player.
            Flip();
        }
        // Otherwise if the input is moving the player left and the player is facing right...
        else if (move < 0 && m_FacingRight)
        {
            // ... flip the player.
            Flip();
        }


        int horizontal = 0;     //Used to store the horizontal move direction.
        int vertical = 0;       //Used to store the vertical move direction.

#if UNITY_STANDALONE || UNITY_WEBPLAYER

        //Check if we are running on iOS, Android, Windows Phone 8 or Unity iPhone
#elif UNITY_IOS || UNITY_ANDROID || UNITY_WP8 || UNITY_IPHONE

        //Check if Input has registered more than zero touches
        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            //Store the first touch detected.
            Touch myTouch = Input.touches[0];

            //Check if the phase of that touch equals Began
            if (myTouch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            {
                //If so, set touchOrigin to the position of that touch
                touchOrigin = myTouch.position;
            }

            //If the touch phase is not Began, and instead is equal to Ended and the x of touchOrigin is greater or equal to zero:
            else if (myTouch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended && touchOrigin.x >= 0)
            {
                //Set touchEnd to equal the position of this touch
                Vector2 touchEnd = myTouch.position;

                //Calculate the difference between the beginning and end of the touch on the x axis.
                float x = touchEnd.x - touchOrigin.x;

                //Calculate the difference between the beginning and end of the touch on the y axis.
                float y = touchEnd.y - touchOrigin.y;

                //Set touchOrigin.x to -1 so that our else if statement will evaluate false and not repeat immediately.
                touchOrigin.x = -1;

                //Check if the difference along the x axis is greater than the difference along the y axis.
                if (Mathf.Abs(x) > Mathf.Abs(y))
                    //If x is greater than zero, set horizontal to 1, otherwise set it to -1
                    horizontal = x > 0 ? 1 : -1;
                else
                    //If y is greater than zero, set horizontal to 1, otherwise set it to -1
                    vertical = y > 0 ? 1 : -1;
            }
        }

#endif
        if (TCKInput.GetAction("jumpBtn", EActionEvent.Up))
        {
            animator.SetBool("jump", false);
        }


        if (TCKInput.GetAction("jumpBtn", EActionEvent.Down) && m_Grounded == true)
        {
            animator.SetBool("jump", true);
            m_Grounded = false;
            m_Rigidbody2D.AddForce(new Vector2(0f, m_JumpForce));
        }



        if (TCKInput.GetAction("fireBtn", EActionEvent.Down))
        {
            animator.SetBool("swing", true);
            m_Collider.enabled = !m_Collider.enabled;
        }

        if (TCKInput.GetAction("fireBtn", EActionEvent.Up))
        {
            animator.SetBool("swing", false);
            m_Collider.enabled = !m_Collider.enabled;
        }

        if (TCKInput.GetAction("slideBtn", EActionEvent.Down))
        {
            if (timeStamp <= Time.time)
            {
                animator.SetBool("slide", true);
                GameObject b = (GameObject)(Instantiate(bullet, transform.position + transform.right * 1.5f, Quaternion.identity));
                b.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(transform.right * 1000);
                timeStamp = Time.time + 5;
            }
        }




        if (TCKInput.GetAction("slideBtn", EActionEvent.Up))
        {
            animator.SetBool("slide", false);
        }

        if (TCKInput.GetAction("right", EActionEvent.Press))
        {
            move = -1;

        }
        if (TCKInput.GetAction("right", EActionEvent.Up))
        {
            animator.SetBool("run", false);
        }


        if (TCKInput.GetAction("left", EActionEvent.Press))
        {
            move = 1;

        }
        if (TCKInput.GetAction("left", EActionEvent.Up))
        {
            animator.SetBool("run", false);
        }

        if (objectCollider.IsTouching(anotherCollider))
        {
            canJump = true;
        }
        else
        {
            canJump = false;
        }



    }

    private void Flip()
    {
        // Switch the way the player is labelled as facing.
        m_FacingRight = !m_FacingRight;

        // Multiply the player's x local scale by -1.
        Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;
        theScale.x *= -1;
        transform.localScale = theScale;
    }



    void Hurt()
    {
        move = 4;
        SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
    }


    protected void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {

        EnemyHealth3 enemy = collision.collider.GetComponent<EnemyHealth3>();

        if (enemy != null)
        {
            move = 0;
            animator.SetBool("death", true);
            m_Rigidbody2D.AddForce(new Vector2(0f, m_JumpForce));
            StartCoroutine(ExecuteAfterTime(.1));
        }

    }


    IEnumerator ExecuteAfterTime(double time)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds((float)time);
        Hurt();
    }

}
```

````
#Code that is on the floor spawner script#
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Floor_Spawn_Script : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject[] obj;

    private float oldPosition;
    private float currentPosition;
    private float ctr = 0;
    private float inte = 10.19f;

    // Use this for initialization
    private void Start()
    {
        oldPosition = transform.position.x;
        AddRoom(ctr * inte);
        ctr += 1;
        AddRoom(ctr * inte);
        ctr += 1;
        AddRoom(ctr * inte);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        currentPosition = transform.position.x;
        if ((currentPosition - oldPosition) <= 9.595f)
        {
            AddRoom(ctr * inte);
            oldPosition = transform.position.x;
            ctr += 1;
        }
    }

    void AddRoom(float roomCenter)
    {
        GameObject room = (GameObject)Instantiate(obj[Random.Range(0, obj.Length)]);
        room.transform.position = new Vector3(roomCenter, 0f, 10f);

    }

}```
````

Comment: Please add your code to the question *as text*.  We can't work with an image.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Can you tell us how your jump logic is set up? My first thought would be that your spawned platforms don't have the right tag set to them if it's checking against that or it doesn't have a collider attached if it's checking against that. But without knowing how your jump logic works I can only speculate.

Comment: My spawned platforms all spawn with box colliders, and my jump is setup through a "isground" variable. The tag is set to "Ground"